# The result returned by the calendarList.list request is empty

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client, service-accounts

I created a service account to make calendar api calls;But when my code runs, everything looks perfect. But the returned data is empty.The api debugging function I provided on the Google webpage can return data when calling it. link => https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list#examples

my java code

```java
package org.test.google;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.CalendarScopes;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.CalendarList;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CalendarTest {
    private static final Set<String> scopes = Arrays.stream(new String[]{
            CalendarScopes.CALENDAR,
            CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_EVENTS,
            CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_EVENTS_READONLY,
            CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY,
            CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_SETTINGS_READONLY,
    }).collect(Collectors.toSet());


    public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        Credential credential = getCredential(httpTransport, jsonFactory);

        Calendar service = new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("space").build();


        CalendarList calendarList = service.calendarList().list().execute();

        System.out.println(calendarList);

        if (calendarList.getItems().size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("no data");
        }
    }


    private static GoogleCredential getCredential(HttpTransport httpTransport, JsonFactory jsonFactory) throws IOException {
        return GoogleCredential.fromStream(
                new FileInputStream("/Users/clk528/Download/google/json/space-0c23309aa763.json"),
                httpTransport,
                jsonFactory
        ).createScoped(scopes);
    }
}
```

result
[image]

[image]

Comment: Has this service account access to the calendars or are you using impersonation? On the calendar API Try this, you make the request as you, and not as the service account

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that a service account is a dummy user which has no web ui interface.  So when you shared access to the calendar with the service account, by domain wide delegation it does not automatically get added to the calendarlist list.

The calendar list is just the list that appears in the bottom left hand corner of the web interface, the web interface when you you share a cleandr with auser and the user accepts that access it will automatically add it to the users calendar list this does not happen with service accounts.

If you want a calendar to appear in the calendar list for the service account you need to have the service account perform a calendarlist.insert to add it

```
CalendarList calendarList = service.calendarList().list().execute();
```

## impersonation

if you set a user to impersonate on your domain i would expect that the calendar.list method to then return the calendar list for that user.

```
.setServiceAccountUser("user@domain.com")
```